# C# Ln to Mathf.Log

Tags: c#, math

How would you go about writing this function in C#?

[image]

I know this has to do with Mathf.Log, but my math is a little rusty. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Mathf` looks like it's for Unity. Unless you're using Unity, you probably want:

```
double x = 1 + (Math.log(v -s) / (10 * Math.log(2)));
```

Comment: Oh, you're right. I am actually using Unity though. Thanks for the help.